# Decode an Image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, jsp, base64

I have a little generated JavaScript from a JSP page that looks like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("image");
elem.src = "Image?step="+step;
```

The code snippet above is called when the user clicks on a button, and `step` is a variable that is increased with every run of the function. `Image` is a Servlet that generates a PNG-encoded Image.

This works, but it is very slow because the Server must generate the Image when the Client wants it. I know I could pre-load the Image, but I thought of a better solution. Since I know how many steps are allowed, I thought of generating the Images when the page is requested, and embed them into the JavaScript, maybe Base64-encoded so that the Image can be viewed on all OS.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how could I implement it? I don't want to use external JavaScript frameworks like jQuery, and I don't care about browsers that are not really common, it'll be enough if it works with Mozilla browsers and Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for data URIs? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme If not, can you please explain what you mean by „decode an image”?

Comment: @lxg I thought I already did. I want to write something like `var imagestring = <base64-encoded-image>` and then decode that image if the browser should show it

Comment: @lxg The link you posted looks like a good method to do so, but `image/png` isn't base64-encoded and I want to have it work on multiple OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to embed the image source into a HTML page, you can do the following:

```
<img id="image" src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />

<script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */
    var img = '<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/file.png')); ?>'
    document.getElementById('image').src = "data:image/png;base64," + image;
/* ]]> */</script>
```

This is supported by pretty much all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri … “Partial support” for IE means that it is limited to images and CSS, but images is what we do here.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m869e2ar/1/

Comment: I thought I mentioned in my question that I use JSP, not PHP. It would be `<%= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image_data) %>`

Comment: It's just an example. Basically, you load a binary image file, base64 encode it and dump it into a JS variable.